# Rotate a CCTexture2D

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, rotation, opengl-es-2.0

So the premise of my problem is that I apply an alpha mask with a fragment shader to a circular CCSprite. Then I want to rotate the CCSprite while keeping the alpha mask in the same position. If I apply the mask and then rotate the sprite, the mask will rotate with the sprite. If I rotate the sprite and then apply the mask, the mask will be in the rotated position because I base it off the texture of the Sprite which never rotates.

Is there a way I can get the cctexture2d to rotate in a way that the mask will stay in place while the sprite is rotated or do I need to apply a custom vertex shader to the mask or the ccpsrite texture? If custom, what would the matrix transformations look like?